# How to use puppeteer-extra plugin with apify puppeteer crawler

Tags: apify

I want to use puppeteer-extra and puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth plugin with. Is ther any way to use this in apify.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use any of the puppeteer extra plug-ins by requiring the modules you want to use and then using this `puppeteerModule` option to link it with the imported `puppeteer` module. Note that you may also want to try the built-in `stealth` option in place of the stealth module - see the links below.

https://sdk.apify.com/docs/typedefs/launch-puppeteer-options#puppeteermodule

https://sdk.apify.com/docs/typedefs/launch-puppeteer-options#stealth

https://sdk.apify.com/docs/typedefs/stealth-options#docsNav

Comment: thanks, Is there any way to make different context for each tab in puppeteer? Like each tab dont know the cookie or session of ther tab

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean and the question doesn't seem related to the previous. If the answer helped you, please accept it as the solution and post the other question in a separate thread of its own @user11887013